# How to connect to FTP and download file using Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, ftp, qt5.9, qtftp

[Toolbar for FTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrILt.jpg)

On the picture you can see my GUI for my test project.
What I want to do is:

Enter a ftp-url in the line-edit, connect/disconnect to the FTP-server and when I am connected, load a file from the server (button on the left).

I have Qt 5.9 and I cant find anything to include QFtp.

How I can solve this?

Comment: `QFtp` is deprecated. You can still download it separatelly and use. If you don't need raw access to FTP, you should use `QNetworkAccessManager`

Comment: Oh, ok. And what  do you think is better  for  my project?

Comment: Common answer: it depends on your needs.

Comment: I think I will have to download the QFtp. I've downloaded it from https://github.com/qt/qtftp. How do I include it into my project?

Comment: I think that first you should try to use official and documented things. But if you still want to complicate your life - you should do it by yourself (use google, to find how to build a Qt module),

Comment: Just use "search" on the site. The question was already answered here.     https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Qt+5+ftp

Answer (score 0):

Please check *QStringList QNetworkAccessManager::supportedSchemes()* method output. Possible you will see *ftp* here and can use regular *QNetworkRequest* class for access to ftp.

Comment: I need to show the directories of the FTP too, is the QNetworkAccessMangager able to do this?